# Javascript to expand  object at runtime?

Tags: javascript

Hi is this possible? say you have the following:

```
var settings = {
  name : 'bilbo',
  age : 63
}
```

Can you dynamically add another property at runtime so it becomes?

```
var settings = {
  name : 'bilbo',
  age : 63,
  eyecolor : 'blue'
}
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript object, not a JSON object. You should have a look at [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: It's an object literal. There is no such thing as a JSON object.

Comment: JSON=javascript object notation. There are no JSON *objects*, there are only JSON *strings* which can be parsed into objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use dot notation to add a new property:

```
var settings = {
  name : 'bilbo',
  age : 63
}

settings.eyecolor = 'blue';

// or: settings['eyecolor'] = 'blue';
// both of the above will do the same thing:
// add a property to your object

console.log(settings);
/* Logs:
{
    name : 'bilbo',
    age : 63,
    eyecolor: 'blue'
}
*/
```

P.S. This is a regular JavaScript object literal. It's got nothing to do with JSON.

JSON is simply a means to express an object/array as a string that looks like JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
settings.eyecolor = 'blue';
```

or

```
settings['eyecolor'] = 'blue';
```

either will add the `eyecolor` field to your settings object at runtime.

```
var settings = {
  name : 'bilbo',
  age : 63
};
settings.eyecolor = 'blue'; // can be run anywhere once settings has been defined
console.log(settings.name, settings.age, settings.eyecolor); // "biblo" 63 "blue"
```

Answer (score 1):

That "JSON" object is a normal JavaScript object. You can do following:

```
settings.eyecolor = 'blue';
```

or

```
settings['eyecolor'] = 'blue';
```

Comment: @FelixKling Did I wrote that JSON is JavaScript? I wrote that "JSON" object he talks about is a normal JavaScript object. I guess I was not clear :).

Comment: Yeah, ok, now I can see it :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
var settings = {
  name : 'bilbo',
  age : 63
}

settings.eyecolor = 'blue';
```

this will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could code it like this:

```
settings.eyecolor = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply;

```
settings["eyecolor"] = "blue";
```

This will then appear in any re-serialized string.